# MasterClass properties not working in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have employee super class like this

```
public  class EmployeeSuperClass
{
    public EmployeeMainTable mainTbl { get; set; }
    public EmployeeEducationDetailTable educationTbl { get; set; }
    public EmployeeAddressTable addressTbl { get; set; }
    public EmployeePreviousCompanyDetailTable previousCompanyDetailTbl { get; set; }
    public EmployeeAssetsTable assetTbl { get; set; }
    public EmployeeFamilyTable familyTbl { get; set; }            
}
```

am including another class in my question that is

```
public partial class EmployeeMainTable
{
    //Some properties
    public virtual List<EmployeeDepartmentTable> employee_DepartmentTable { get; set; }
}
```

the EmployeedepartmentTable contains department id DepartmentName

to get all department I have written code like this

```
public List<EmployeeDepartmentTable> GetDepartments()
{
     List<EmployeeDepartmentTable> departmentList = new List<EmployeeDepartmentTable>();
     var departments = from dept in db.EMP_DEPT_TBL where dept.IS_ACTV == true select dept;
     foreach (var result in departments)
     {
          departmentList.Add(new EmployeeDepartmentTable { DepartmentId= result.DEPT_ID, DepartmentName = result.DEPT_NM, DepartmentIsActive = result.IS_ACTV });
     }
     return departmentList;
 }
```

in my controller getmethod

am calling above method like this

```
[httpget]
  public ActionResult CreateEmployeeBasicDetails(EmployeeSuperClass employeeSuperClass)
  {
     employeeSuperClass.mainTbl.employee_DepartmentTable = dt.GetDepartments();=>giving   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: debug your self and check where your object not initialized? as you mention your code it can be due to your  employeeSuperClass.mainTbl.employee_DepartmentTable is null or in your fuction GetDepartments() may be your var departments is null so check your variable vaues

Comment: thank u for ur answer I got answer

Answer (score 0):

of course this is going to cause an Exception!

```
[httpget]
  public ActionResult CreateEmployeeBasicDetails(EmployeeSuperClass employeeSuperClass)
        {
            employeeSuperClass.mainTbl.employee_DepartmentTable = dt.GetDepartments();=>giving Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

`dt` is not set to anything!

to fix:
change this to static

```
public static List<EmployeeDepartmentTable> GetDepartments()
```

then in your controller ....

```
 employeeSuperClass.mainTbl.employee_DepartmentTable = EmployeeDepartmentTable.GetDepartments();
```

I am assuming here that the GetDepartments() is located in EmployeeDepartmentTable class ,  whichever class it is in is where you wil find it  - ex.   `MyClassWhereGetDepartmentsIsIn.GetDepartments();`

**UPDATE**

try this

```
employeeSuperClass.mainTbl.employee_DepartmentTable departments = dt.GetDepartments()
```

Comment: I have defined getDepartments() method in different class that is named bindingdropdownlist.cs

Comment: i have created bindingdropdownlist dt=new bindingdropdownlist();

Comment: ok - so do what I said and make it static , then : BindingDropDownList.GetDepartments();

Comment: oh , ok , i got it ,  one sec

Comment: employeeSuperClass.mainTbl.employee_DepartmentTable departments = dt.GetDepartments() this wont work I want to send all departments to bind dropdownlist in view

Comment: you just repeated what I put in my answer in your comment , does that mean it worked or didn't work?

Comment: Sorry for mistake  That is wont work and it works for employeemaintable tbl=new employeemaintable()  tbl.employee_departments=dt.getdepartments() but I want superclass.emplmaintable.employeedepartments=dt.getdepartments()

Answer (score -1):

May be you don't have initialized employeeSuperClass.mainTbl property

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateEmployeeBasicDetails(EmployeeSuperClass employeeSuperClass)
{
    employeeSuperClass.mainTbl = new EmployeeMainTable();
    employeeSuperClass.mainTbl.employee_DepartmentTable = dt.GetDepartments();
}
```

It's good habit to initialize such properties in class constructor.

Comment: you mean : employeeSuperClass.mainTbl empTable = new EmployeeMainTable();

Comment: Thanks a lot ANAND & Scott Selby employeeSuperClass.mainTbl = new EmployeeMainTable();
its works fine